# Select query custom calculated column to round to 2 decimal places

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with some columns a,b, i need to add a custom column c_avg which will have the value
c_avg = a*100/b upto 2 decimal values

my original table is some thing like this

```
id a b
1  1 2
2  2 3
3  2 0
```

I have come up with this query but seems as this returns me value as integer.

```
select round( CAST((CASE WHEN b=0 THEN '0.00'
        ELSE round(((a*100)/b),2)
   END ) as numeric) , 2) as c_avg
from table_name
```

i get output to this as

```
a b c_avg
1 2 0
2 3 0
```

i need some thing like this

```
a b c_avg
1 2 0.50
2 3 0.66
2 0 0
```

My Postgresql version on amazon redshift is PostgreSQL 8.0.2

There is also a few things I'm doing with this table

```
select sum(a) as aa, sum(b) as bb, groub_by_column
round( CAST((CASE WHEN sum(b)=0 THEN '0.00'
    ELSE round(((sum(a)*100)/sum(b)),2)
    END ) as numeric) , 2) as c_avg
from table group by groub_by_column
```

This returns me value to 0 and not to 0.*

Thanks

The division operation in postgresql truncates to integer value
just found that

```
select round((4000/576::float),3) as result;
```

adding meta **::float** to the division operation gives the desired result, it does not truncates the output to integer value.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The division operation in postgresql truncates to integer value just found that

```
select round((4000/576::float),3) as result;
```

adding meta **::float** to the division operation gives the desired result, it does not truncates the output to integer value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

While working on integers, the result is also an integer - multiply by a float value to get a float result:

```
SELECT
    sum(a) as aa,
    sum(b) as bb,
    group_by_column,
    CASE
        WHEN 0 = sum(b) THEN 0.0
        ELSE ROUND(100.0 * sum(b) / sum(b), 2)
    END AS c_avg
FROM table_name
GROUP BY group_by_column
```

Comment: Please check the eddited section

Comment: @rohitmb, I've expanded my solution to include also the GROUP BY part

Answer (score 1):

Postgres does integer division, so try this version of your query:

```
select round((CASE WHEN b=0 THEN 0.00
                   ELSE a*100.0)/b
              END), 2) as c_avg
from table_name;
```

You can also do this by converting the result to a decimal:

```
select cast((case when b = 1 then 0 else a*100.0/b end) as decimal(5, 2)) as c_avg
from table_name;
```

Comment: hey, not known to this, what does decimal(5, 2) do in this

Comment: Please check other details added

Comment: @rohitmb . . . `decimal()` is a fixed width numeric type.  It is an alternative to `round()` and part of the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT to_char (1/2::FLOAT, 'FM999999990.00');
--- RESULT: 0.50
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT round (2/3::DECIMAL, 2)::TEXT
--- RESULT: 0.67
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old question, but I found that casting to **DECIMAL(10, 2)** might be the best/easiest way to round to 2 decimal places in redshift. None of the other answers worked for me.

```
SELECT 10.4494685::DECIMAL(10,2)
-- OUTPUT 10.45
```

Answer (score -1):

you need cast

```
select round( (2/3), 2) produces 0
select round( (2/3::numeric), 2) produces 0.67
```

Comment: select round( (2/3), 2) produces 0
select round( (2/3::numeric), 2) produces 1

Comment: @atiruz you are wrong. I [testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/8885) that and select round( (2/3::numeric), 2) produces 0.67

Comment: depends on the version of postgresql, I auditioned with 4 different versions

Comment: The question is on postgres 8.0.2.  see more in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-math.html